# Is every second countable locally compact Hausdorff space normal?

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

I know that there are locally compact Hausdorff spaces that aren't normal. Are there examples which are second countable?

Comment: Nope. Locally compact Hausdorff spaces are regular, regular Hausdorff second countable spaces are metrizable, and metrizable spaces are normal. A regular Lindelof space is not necessarily metrizable but it is normal.

Comment: @bof Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This search in pi-Base shows one reason why such spaces must be normal: [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Second%20Countable%2BLocally%20Compact%2B%24T_2%24%2B~Normal](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Second%20Countable%2BLocally%20Compact%2B%24T_2%24%2B%7ENormal)

In short, Hausdorff locally compact spaces are completely regular, and second countable regular Hausdorff spaces spaces are metrizable, and therefore normal.